# Scala check if Future[Seq[String]] isEmpty

Tags: scala, future, sequences

I would like to check if a Future[Seq[String]] is Empty and I am using

```
if(!Future.sequence(sortSeq).isEmpty){
//doSomething
}
```

but it throws me error ?

Comment: What is the type of `sortSeq`? Is it Seq[Future[String]]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the type of `sortSeq` is `Future[Seq[String]]`, so you don't need `Future.sequence`.

You have to wait for result of your `Future` and then check if result is empty:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
if(!Await.result(sortSeq.map{_.isEmpty}, 5.seconds){
  //doSomething
}
```

If you can execute `doSomething` in a different thread you could try this:

```
val someRusultFuture = sortSeq.map{ rs =>
  if(!rs.isEmpty){
    //doSomething
  }
}
```

but you'll have to wait for result of `someRusultFuture`.

Proof it works:

```
scala> import concurrent.{Future, Await}
import concurrent.{Future, Await}

scala> import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

scala> val sortSeq = Future{ Thread.sleep(10000); Seq("a") }
sortSeq: scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[String]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3592f7c6

scala> Await.result(sortSeq.map{_.isEmpty}, 11.seconds)
res1: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
[error]  both method any2Ensuring in object Predef of type [A](x: A)Ensuring[A]
[error]  and method any2ArrowAssoc in object Predef of type [A](x: A)ArrowAssoc[A]
[error]  are possible conversion functions from scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[String]] to ?M
[error] one error found

Comment: @princessofpersia: What is the type of sortSeq?

Comment: Yes I tried that too, doesnt work. sortSeq is of type Future[Seq[String]] and I want to check if this Sequence is empty.

Comment: @princessofpersia: It works fine, I've added the example of code. I suppose the error is somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`Future.sequence` method is used to transform a `TraversableOnce[Future[A]]` into a `Future[TraversableOnce[A]]`.

I think you can forget whether the `Seq` is empty or not and just work with the `Seq` using the `map` function of `Future`

```
  val s = Future[Seq[String]](Seq("s", "e", "q"))
  val p  = s.map(s => s.foreach(println))
```

This works because, the empty check is performed implicitly in the background. In the below example, when the `Seq` is empty, nothing will be printed.

```
scala>   val s = Future[Seq[String]](Seq.empty)
s: scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[String]] = Future(<not completed>)

scala>   val p  = s.map(s => s.foreach(println))
p: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = Future(<not completed>)
```

If you **really** want to perform an empty check, you can **also** use `withFilter`.

With a non empty `Seq`

```
scala>   val s = Future[Seq[String]](Seq("s", "e", "q"))
s: scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[String]] = Future(Success(List(s, e, q)))

scala>   val p  = s.withFilter(_.nonEmpty).map(s => s.foreach(println))
p: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = Future(<not completed>)

s
e
q
```

With an empty `Seq`

```
scala>   val s = Future[Seq[String]](Seq.empty)
s: scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[String]] = Future(Success(List()))

scala>   val p  = s.withFilter(_.nonEmpty).map(s => s.foreach(println))
p: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = Future(<not completed>)
```

Also you can do the empty check as mentioned in the above answer

```
val someRusultFuture = sortSeq.map{ rs =>
  if(!rs.isEmpty){
    //doSomething
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.